# Oracle 11g - Want to know current row information, especially PK

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, sequence, procedure

I made a trigger like below.
`test_suc_func` always return varchar2 "00".

```
create or replace procedure call_func (v_a_id  IN NUMBER)
is 
begin 
update A_TBL set created = test_suc_func() where a_id = v_a_id;
end;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER a_trigger
  AFTER
    INSERT ON A_TBL
  -- FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
  call_func(a_seq.currVal);
exception
  when others then 
  update A_TBL set rc='99'
  where a_id = a_id;  
END;
```

I expect this PLSQL to execute followings.

1. When data insert into A_TBL, it calls a function.
2. When it fails, it update that COLUMN.

The problem is when I wrote in `exception` statement, updates all rows in A_TBL.

Since PK of A_TBL is sequence, I can get that with `a_seq.currVal`, but as you see can not use sequence in `where` statement.

Q. How can I refer current row data in trigger like `this` keyword in javascript?

I have tried `:new` and `:old`, but It pops up a weird window in sqldeveloper. Thanks :D bb

=================== 2015 09 18

I edited the post, since I got an error. Some of `a_seq`s change to `a_id`s.

Comment: You can't run an `UPDATE` statement on the table on which the trigger fired. And you don't need it. `:new.created := test_suc_func();` is all you need in the trigger

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This code is simple version. In fact, It will call a function in the remote database. - I do not get your first statement. The code I provided is actually works. The problem is it updates all rows, since I wrote my where clause like `a_id=a_id`. What I want to write is something like `a_id = this.a_id` or `a_id = a_seq.currVal`. Thanks anyway b

Comment: Well in a statement level trigger there is no such thing as "the current row" because it is fired for the _statement_ not for each row. And the statement might have affected millions of rows.

Comment: Several issues I have, but not sure why you gave up on row level trigger (and went to statement level), since it seems row level is what you want (so you can refer to :new and :old).  Try putting "set define off" at top and then run as script, or put just the trigger code in a separate editor window and run execute statement (instead of a script).  Or, put in a sql file and run in sqlplus (@myfile.sql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you need to modify columns of inserted record.
For such case you don't need update statements in trigger.
You just need `BEFORE INSERT` trigger with `FOR EACH ROW` option.
In such case you may just assign new value for
`:new.created` and `:new.rc`, and they will be inserted in `created` and `rc` columns.
Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER a_trigger
  BEFORE
    INSERT ON A_TBL
    FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
  :new.created = test_suc_func();
exception
  when others then 
    :new.rc = '99';
END;
```

You can't modify :new variables in `AFTER` trigger and can't access them without `FOR EACH ROW` option. Also you can't call DML (insert/update/delete) on some table from `FOR EACH ROW` trigger on the same table (table is mutating).

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, in my situation have to update after insert. In this project, insert my DB table first, than call remote function which returns response code. After I receive the response code from remote, update the original row(which is already inserted).

Comment: There are 2 ways of solving this task:
1) pass a_tbl.rowtype to your function, or just list of columns that you need inside (in such case you don't need to query this row in your function, so you may use BEFORE trigger). Then use :new. variables in trigger to set new values passed from function. (don't use UPDATE in trigger or in function)
2) run job from trigger, it will start after insert is committed, then function needs to update this row. (but in such case there will be gap after commit before function updates this row and commits the result when these 2 columns are not defined)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is much better way than this. However I found a detour.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER a_trigger
  AFTER
    INSERT ON A_TBL
  -- FOR EACH ROW    
DECLARE
  tmp_id number;
BEGIN
  select a_seq.currVal into tmp_id from dual;
  call_func(tmp_id);
exception
  when others then 
  update A_TBL set rc='99'
  where a_id = tmp_id;  
END;
```

I have declared a temporary variable in trigger. 
And refer that. Now I update only current row when I failed.

I am still looking for more efficient and clever answer for this problem. Thanks

Comment: This is not going to work if more than one row was inserted. I still don't see why you can't (or don't want to) use a row level trigger and assign the `:new` value directly

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am new with PLSQL, but is there any case insert several rows at once? I assume that in insert statement, the target is only one record at once. I will check I could use row level trigger with `after` event.